# SSRS 2016 Fix a size of Rectangle

Tags: reporting-services, visualization, ssrs-2016, cockpit-cms

I have a rectangles in my Cockpit with an Image Background. Earlier I have put the Images on this rectangle as Buttons. Now the requierments were changed and I am putting as a button a TextBox with an Image Background so that I can make drill down Buttons. 
The Problem is that it changes the size of rectangle in browser or in visual Studio(Preview).
How can I fix the size of rectangle ?

This Image is in VisualStudio Design [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wDEa.png)
This Image is in Browser[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGFWi.png)
I am clicking on "Produktivität" the drill down menu opens but still the Rectangle doesn't have the whole size [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUYkW.png)

The Rectangle should have the following size which I gave in Properties[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0GBN.png)
Thank you in advance!
Ghukas

Comment: Try changing the report property `Consume Container Whitespace` to `True`. If that does not work , post some more info, such as your report design, current results and expected results.

Comment: Thanks for Response!

I am new in Reporting and I couldn't find the Consume Container Whitespace.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I have added Some info!

Comment: @AlanSchofield I have changed Consume Container Whitespace to True. It doesnt help!